# MySQL Multiple Joins/Lookups for result set

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm not sure how to word this type of action to try and find help on it.

I have a table ('shifts') that is a list of dates for the start of each work week, and 5 shift fields.  The shift fields all have employee user id's (user_id).

I need to make queries to select a specific week or a range of weeks where I convert the user id's into first+last+uid combinations.

Right now, for a single week lookup, the query is taking 7 seconds to run.   Could anyone point me towards a method for multiple lookups against a single query that would run much faster?   I'm not exactly sure how to refer to what I'm trying to do here if anyone has an idea of a key word or phrase for this type of action I could search on.  Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT s.shift_week, 
CONCAT(w1.first_name, ' ', e1.last_name, ' (', e1.user_id, ')' ) AS slot_1,
CONCAT(w2.first_name, ' ', e2.last_name, ' (', e2.user_id, ')' ) AS slot_2,
CONCAT(w3.first_name, ' ', e3.last_name, ' (', e3.user_id, ')' ) AS slot_3,
CONCAT(w4.first_name, ' ', e4.last_name, ' (', e4.user_id, ')' ) AS slot_4,
CONCAT(w5.first_name, ' ', e5.last_name, ' (', e5.user_id, ')' ) AS slot_5
FROM work_shifts.shifts AS s
LEFT JOIN employee_directroy.employees e1 ON o.slot_1 = e1.user_id 
LEFT JOIN employee_directroy.employees e2 ON o.slot_1 = e2.user_id 
LEFT JOIN employee_directroy.employees e3 ON o.slot_1 = e3.user_id 
LEFT JOIN employee_directroy.employees e4 ON o.slot_1 = e4.user_id 
LEFT JOIN employee_directroy.employees e5 ON o.slot_1 = e5.user_id 
WHERE o.shift_week = '2017-11-26'
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You reference `o.slot_1` and `o.shift_week` but you don't declare any table alias for `o`. I think you are editing this query and not posting the real query you tried. Also, I agree with Strawberry, any query optimization question must include at least the table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`) and the EXPLAIN for the query.

Comment: What is `w1`?..